# Full Outer Join not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, join

I want to make a view from these tables. The first inner join works as expected and brings a new column with **AuspraegungID**  from which I want to connect to the  **ArtikelVarianten** table

At the moment I get a view with all ID that have a counterpart in ArtikelVarianten. But some articles dont have that ID (its set to zero, and no match in the target table) so they are ommitted in the current selection
But I want to include them, and I thought thats where the **full outer join** comes in.

```
Select Distinct [A].[Artikelnummer],
  [A].[Bezeichnung1],
  [S].[AuspraegungID],
  [A].[USER_SkuDe] As [Parent SKU],
  [AV].[USER_SkuDe] As [Varianten SKU]
From [dbo].[KHKArtikel] [A]
  inner Join  [dbo].[LBSysStock] [S] 
    On [S].[Artikelnummer] = [A].[Artikelnummer]
  Full Outer Join [dbo].[LBSysArtikelVarianten] [AV] 
  On [S].[AuspraegungID] = [AV].[AuspraegungID] 
    And [AV].[Artikelnummer] = [A].[Artikelnummer]
```

Comment: Please have a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: Show us a  sample of rows and output - and what from it is not expected. (see the links in the first comment,by McNets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd encourage you to read the blog post [Be Careful When Mixing INNER and OUTER Joins](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/10/11/mixing-inner-outer-joins-sql/).

> If you use Derived Tables (or nested joins) the way you'd use
>   parenthesis in a math or boolean equation to express your logical
>   order of precedence, you can make your code cleaner and more readable
>   and you can ensure that you get back the exact results you intended.

I don't know if this will solve your problem, as you did not post any table definitions or sample data, but I'd try changing your query to encapsulate the `inner join` into a derived table and then join the derived table using the `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  Here is an example (not tested):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ij].[Artikelnummer]
    ,[ij].[Bezeichnung1]
    ,[ij].[AuspraegungID]
    ,[ij].[USER_SkuDe] AS [Parent SKU]
    ,[AV].[USER_SkuDe] AS [Varianten SKU]
FROM (
    SELECT [A].[Artikelnummer]
        ,[A].[Bezeichnung1]
        ,[A].[USER_SkuDe]
        ,[S].[AuspraegungID]
    FROM [dbo].[KHKArtikel] [A]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[LBSysStock] [S]
        ON [S].[Artikelnummer] = [A].[Artikelnummer]
    ) ij --inner join
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[LBSysArtikelVarianten] [AV]
    ON [ij].[AuspraegungID] = [AV].[AuspraegungID]
        AND [AV].[Artikelnummer] = [ij].[Artikelnummer]
```